# Windows 11 mail / outlook.live.com - how to delete recent contacts?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, windows-11, windows-mail

There is an infuriating thing that is happening to my Mail app in Windows, however it occurs also in Outlook mail online.

Let's say my company is Alpha, and the email is `me@alpha.net`. I'm a software developer, so I tested sending e-mails from my web application made for Beta company. I used my own company account as the sender, but set the sender's NAME to `Beta` - to mark them correctly as sent by the tested app. My Windows Mail receives the email.

That's how my nightmare started. It was a few years ago, but since then - I cannot use my company e-mail in Windows Mail. When I type "me@" the Mail app not only completes it, but replaces the whole address with "BETA". I can't rename it, I can't remove the name leaving only the e-mail address.

It looks like my company e-mail is forever changed to BETA company with no possibility to change it or delete it.

What I tried:

- reinstall the Mail app.
- reinstall Windows (yes, with format).
- resetting the Mail app data.
- resetting the People app data.
- adding my company mail as a new contact and set it a correct name.

None of it worked. It seems hopeless. It looks like it's hardwired into my Microsoft account and it will stay there forever.

It seems also like a vulnerability - when you send a fake email to your victim with specifically composed sender header you could break someone else's contacts and make the person send their sensitive data to someone else, like you for example.

My question is - is it really hopeless and nothing can be done, or there is a magic way to delete recent contacts or just fix the invalid entry?

IDK, maybe there is a not well know option of the Microsoft accounts that allows purging all personal data? I think Google has something like that.

**UPDATE:**

I checked all folders of my Outlook account for the email with the offending sender. I've found emails in my `Sent items` folder. I purged all emails containing offending sender.

Then I reset both People and Mail and Calendar applications (full reset, with deleting data). To be absolutely sure, I reinstalled the Mail and Calendar application. I set accounts EXCEPT the Outlook one, and for now it works correctly, I can enter my email without it being replaced with invalid sender's name. However, I was afraid to add the Outlook account yet...

It worked until I've done it. After adding my Outlook account the offending unremovable contact reappeared.

So I'm sure now it's the Microsoft Outlook account issue. The only way FOR NOW to be able to use Mail and Calendar application is to delete the Outlook's e-mail account and just not use it. When only other accounts are used, the application works correctly.

I deleted the Outlook's account. Now it works. Without resetting anything. Maybe there's a way to include the account, but just disable using contacts from that account.

Still, the problem is not solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and found there's a way to do in in Outlook and the web interface at outlook.com (see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-suggested-recipients-in-the-to-cc-and-bcc-boxes-with-auto-complete-dbe46e31-c098-4881-8cf7-66b037bce23e - scroll down to "Delete one or more suggested recipients in the Auto-Complete List") but I couldn't find a way to delete "Recent People" entries, nor disable the Recent People/Autocomplete list in the Mail app itself.

I removed the problem entry via the web interface hoping it might carry through to the Mail app, but it didn't. I waited about 5-10 minutes and restarted the app a few times in case it hadn't resynced but still no joy. I then did a reset of the Mail app via Windows Settings->App and the problem "Person" was gone! :)

So perhaps try removing the "BETA" entry via Outlook or outlook.com first, then reset the Mail app.

Comment: Hey, how did you remove the entry via outlook.com? There is no option to delete the invalid contact. It appears on autocomplete list as soon as I enter the first letter of the address (in outlook.com). The contact doesn't exist on ANY list except autocomplete list. It is totally unremovable. My solution was to quit using all Microsoft Mail software (online and offline). I use Vivaldi instead, it works million times better. BTW, I submitted several bugs to M$ feedback, they fixed NONE. This software is dead to me.